# send MMS image from server

Tags: blackberry, mms, mms-gateway

How do I send an image through [MMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_Messaging_Service) from a server?

I went through the JDE samples, and I know how to send an attachment from the BlackBerry file system.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the recipient's carrier.   Some operators [run email gateways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways) that will send an MMS based on attachments in the email.